# Cannot Create Table after Lowercased all text in MySQL Dump file

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I'm having an error restoring tables which have Foreign Keys after lowercasing the contents of a mysql dump file. 
My goal is to lowercase all structure in a mysql database. 
I used vim to lowercase all contents of a mysqldump file when trying to restore the database, this is the error I get.

```
$  mysql -u [user] -p[password] dme < mysqldump.sql
    ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 399: Can't create table 'dme.contacts' (errno: 121)
```

The restore is error'ing out on any table which has Foreign Key contstraints.  If I remove lines after the Primary Key for each table, the entire restore works fine.

My question is, what is causing this and how can I keep my Foreign Keys in the process?

1. Lowercased.sql example which results in the error (fyi prior to dme.contacts there are multiple tables which are created just fine. Only tables w/ Foreign Keys and Contstraints have issues.)

   ```
   drop table if exists `contacts`;
   /*!40101 set @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
   /*!40101 set character_set_client = utf8 */;
   create table `contacts` (
     `contactid` int(11) not null auto_increment,
     `firstname` varchar(100) default null,
     `lastname` varchar(100) not null,
     `fullname` varchar(200) not null,
     `dob` datetime default null,
     `sex` char(1) default null,
     `voided` datetime default null,
     `vendorid` int(11) not null,
     `contacttypeid` int(11) default null,
     `comments` varchar(1500) default null,
     primary key (`contactid`),
     key `fk_contacts_vendors` (`vendorid`),
     key `fk_contacts_contacttype` (`contacttypeid`),
     constraint `fk_contacts_contacttype` foreign key (`contacttypeid`) references                 `contacttype` (`contacttypeid`) on delete no action on update no action,
     constraint `fk_contacts_vendors` foreign key (`vendorid`) references `vendors`         (`vendorid`) on delete no action on update no action
   ) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
   /*!40101 set character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

   --
   -- dumping data for table `contacts`
   --

   lock tables `contacts` write;
   /*!40000 alter table `contacts` disable keys */;
   /*!40000 alter table `contacts` enable keys */;
   unlock tables;
   ```
2. Original from the mysqldump.sql (No Error)

   ```
   --
   -- Table structure for table `Contacts`
   --

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Contacts`;
   /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
   /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
   CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
     `ContactId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `FirstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `LastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     `FullName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     `DOB` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Voided` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `ContactTypeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Comments` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ContactId`),
     KEY `FK_Contacts_Vendors` (`VendorID`),
     KEY `FK_Contacts_ContactType` (`ContactTypeID`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_Contacts_ContactType` FOREIGN KEY (`ContactTypeID`) REFERENCES `ContactType` (`ContactTYpeID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
     CONSTRAINT `FK_Contacts_Vendors` FOREIGN KEY (`VendorID`) REFERENCES `Vendors` (`VendorId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

   --
   -- Dumping data for table `Contacts`
   --

   LOCK TABLES `Contacts` WRITE;
   /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Contacts` DISABLE KEYS */;
   /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Contacts` ENABLE KEYS */;
   UNLOCK TABLES;
   ```

Comment: You cannot. Names are case sensitive in MySql.

Comment: Are you restoring the dump to a fresh database?

Comment: Yes @bansi this is restoring to a fresh database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the constrain name. Sample:

```
constraint `fk_contacts_contacttype` foreign key (`contacttypeid`) ....
```

To

```
constraint foreign key (`contacttypeid`) ...
```

Comment: That worked.  Here is the edited version which worked just fine. [http://pastebin.com/ReJrvZVH](http://pastebin.com/ReJrvZVH)